How to set the random seed in TensorFlow's RandomSearch for hyperparameter tuning?
I'm using TensorFlow, with automated hyper-parameter tuning via RandomSearch, to train a simple gradient-boosted trees model as follows:
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_decision_forests as tfdf

tuner = tfdf.tuner.RandomSearch(num_trials=50)
tuner = tfdf.tuner.RandomSearch(num_trials=50, use_predefined_hps=True)
tuned_model = tfdf.keras.GradientBoostedTreesModel(tuner=tuner, task=tfdf.keras.Task.REGRESSION, sampling_method="GOSS")
tuned_model.fit(train_ds)

Where train_ds is my training data.
To speed this up, I want to run each of the 50 hyper-parameter tuning trials in parallel across 50 CPUs. So I've set num_trials==1 on each CPU and used python multiprocessing to run each trial as one worker.
However, I'm running into the problem that on every CPU, the trial produces an identical result. This is not a problem with multiprocessing, because it does not occur when I fix the hyper-parameters to different values, manually. I therefore think that it must be that TensorFlow sets an identical random seed on every CPU.
I've looked everywhere for a way to set the random seed dynamically on each CPU, but there's no way to set the seed within RandomSearch, and tf.random.set_seed(seed) appears to do nothing.
So basically, where is the random seed for RandomSearch set, and how can I change it?
And as an aside, why is this so difficult to do? I'm new to TensorFlow but this seems like an obvious way to speed up a randomized hyper-parameter search. Am I missing something?

To resolve the issue you're facing with TensorFlow Decision Forests' RandomSearch and obtaining identical results across CPUs, consider handling random seeds externally or customizing how trials are executed to ensure that each trial uses a different seed. This approach is crucial for achieving varied outcomes from each trial run. If feasible, migrating to TensorFlow 2.x, which offers more streamlined and contemporary APIs, could also provide enhanced functionality for managing such scenarios effectively.
